# How to call another generator in redux-saga?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I would like to fetch detail information with getTemplateCoins generator from each item's id of fetched list in the same generator. My idea is to iterate through active and unactive list and return new list with additional information

MyCollectionSaga

```
export function* getMyCollectionDetails(api) {
  try {
   const responseDetails = yield makeRequest(api, api.getMySocialProfile, null);
   const responseBadges = yield makeRequest(api, api.getBadges, null);
   const responseTemplates = yield makeRequest(api, api.getTemplates, null);

  if (responseDetails.ok && responseBadges.ok && responseTemplates.ok) {
    const templates = responseTemplates.data.results.map((e) => parseTemplate(e));
    const active = templates.filter((e) => e.active);
    const unactive = templates.filter((e) => !e.active);
 
    //Would like to call getTemplateCoins here with templateId as item's id of active and         unactive list above. 
    //then save them in the new array and pass them to getMyCollectionDetailSuccess below
    yield put(
      MyCollectionsActions.getMyCollectionDetailsSuccess(
       responseDetails.data.result,
       responseBadges.data.result,
       active,
       unactive
     )
    );
   }
 } catch (error) {`
   log(error);
 }
```

}

```
export function* getTemplateCoins(api, { templateId }) {
  try {
    const params = { templateId };
    const response = yield makeRequest(api, api.getTemplateCoins, params);

    if (response.ok) {
      const coinsCollections = response.data.results.coins.filter((e) => e.inCollection);
      const coinsMissing = response.data.results.coins.filter((e) => !e.inCollection);

      const coins = [
        { title: i18n.t('common:collectionTemplateSectionCollected'), data: coinsCollections       },
        { title: i18n.t('common:collectionTemplateSectionMissing'), data: coinsMissing },
  ];

      yield put(CollectionTemplateActions.getTemplateCoinsSuccess(coins));
    } else {
      yield put(
        CollectionTemplateActions.getTemplateCoinsFailure(i18n.t('common:genericErrorMessage'))
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    log(error);
    yield put(
      CollectionTemplateActions.getTemplateCoinsFailure(i18n.t('common:genericErrorMessage'))
   );
 }
```

}`

Here is the redux function
MyCollectionRedux

```
const getMyCollectionDetails = (state) => {
 return { ...state, isLoading: true, error: false, message: '' };
};

const getMyCollectionDetailsSuccess = (
  state,
  { socialProfile, allBadges, templatesActivated, templatesUnactivated }
) => {
  
 return {
   ...state,
   socialProfile,
   allBadges,
   templatesActivated,
   templatesUnactivated,
   isLoading: false,
   error: false,
  };
};

const getMyCollectionDetailsFailure = (state, { message }) => {
  return { ...state, message, isLoading: false, error: true };
};
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @LinDu How to call getTemplateCoins inside getCollectionDetails and save return data to the active array